# How to properly ask a question where the author does not know where the problem is?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

A few days ago I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429245/why-does-my-site-jump-on-first-load), which was eventually closed as off-topic since it does not provide any code but an external link to the website that had the issue.

The author's problem in this case was that they didn't know where their issue was and thus could not possibly know which part of their code to post, expect from the entire code of the webpage.

I understand why it is closed as off-topic, but I want to ask how one would properly post such a question and avoid it getting closed?

Comment: *"they didn't know where their issue was and thus could not possibly know which part of their code to post"* - then they should have solved that problem by using basic debugging techniques, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This may well have obviated the need for the question at all!

Comment: That is true, finding where the problem is might be enough to fix the issue. But if one cannot debug its code he should not post to SO anyway?

Comment: No, we require a minimal example, this isn't a debugging service. The OP could have tried to create a Stack Snippet example, rather than sending people off-site. Also, why have you tagged it [tag:twitter-bootstrap]? That doesn't seem to be particularly relevant.

Comment: The issue is about the `affix.js` component of twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Ah OK; understood, I hadn't realised that was specific to the library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primary purpose of SO is to create a repository of common problems which every programmer may stumble across sooner or later, and help them find an existing solution to that problem instantly. SO's purpose is not to solve any one person's individual problem for them.

*"Here's a link to my site, something's wrong with it, I have no idea what"* **is not a problem that will ever constructively apply to anyone else.** Once the answer has been found and the problem has been fixed there isn't even a clear problem description anymore. This is not a *problem description with a solution*, it's a crowdsourced debugging task. It is off-topic for SO any which way you turn it.

If the question does not pass the *"would anyone else with the same problem ever search for and find this question"*-sniff test, then there's no way to ask it on SO.

Comment: I totally understand that and that was the purpose of my question here. I have been in such cases where my debugging process failed me after hours (or days) of effort. It would be nice to know how to ask here a question that appears vague to the readers without being downvoted and closed.

Comment: Well, consider that not every problem is a nail for which SO is the right hammer. SO is great for certain types of problems and questions. Vague wishy washy problems are *not* part of that. There's only so much a single web service can do for you. Find other avenues to get your problem solved. The Chat may be one avenue, relevant mailing lists another, or maybe colleagues, friends, local user groups, mentors, paid freelancers.

Answer (score 7):

Being able to debug your code and at least narrow down things to a minimal repro is IMHO a prerequisite for using Stack Overflow. Even if you're terrible at it there's always the option to do some "binary search debugging".

> I want to ask how one would properly post such a question

There is no way to ask "such a question". The only viable option is that the OP invests time in finding the root cause, or at least a small repro of the scenario, and post that.